# How do I sort a groupby by the a sum of group?

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I'm currently having a issue, its very hard to explain. I have a Dataframe that has been groupby into 4s. Each row of the entry has a column called Value.

```
                 Name      Role  Cost  Value  
0       Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
1   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
2           Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
3         Greg Ritcher  Lookout   200     25
4       Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
5   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
6           Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
7          Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
8          Baby Hitsuo   Driver   950     35
9   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
10          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
11         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
```

Essentially I want the groups to be sorted in descending order by the sum of the Values in each groupby.

It seems like it should be simply. I've tried a lot of things and get a variety of errors such as: sum() not and atttribute, str issues, dataframe object issues. I've tried using the sort, sum, lambda, agg funtions. I cant believe I'm having trouble sorting the groupby by an descending order. Here is a snippet and visuals.

The groupby does this essentially to the above dataframe:

```
0
                 Name     Role  Cost  Value
0      Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
1  Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
2          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
3        Greg Ritcher  Lookout   200     25

Cost: 6700   Value: 160

1
                 Name     Role  Cost  Value
4      Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
5  Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
6          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
7         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30

Cost: 6750   Value: 165

2
                  Name     Role  Cost  Value
8          Baby Hitsuo   Driver   950     35
9   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
10          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
11         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30

Cost: 6700   Value: 161
```

When I sort I want the dataframe and end result to print:

```
4       Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
5   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
6           Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
7          Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
8          Baby Hitsuo   Driver   950     35
9   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
10          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
11         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
0       Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
1   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
2           Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
3         Greg Ritcher  Lookout   200     25
```

Here is the Dataframe and code:

```
from pprint import pprint
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data= [['Johnny Tsunami','Driver',1000,39],
['Michael B. Jackson','Pistol',2500,46],
['Bobby Zuko','Pistol',3000,50],
['Greg Ritcher','Lookout',200,25],
['Johnny Tsunami','Driver',1000,39],
['Michael B. Jackson','Pistol',2500,46],
['Bobby Zuko','Pistol',3000,50],
['Appa Derren','Lookout',250,30],
['Baby Hitsuo','Driver',950,35],
['Michael B. Jackson','Pistol',2500,46],
['Bobby Zuko','Pistol',3000,50],
['Appa Derren','Lookout',250,30]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Role','Cost','Value'])

#groupby4s
gr = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index))/4)
```

Comment: I take it the output is not in the correct order

Comment: any feedback on the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

First create the groups of 4, sort them, and save the index order (changed the code to build the groups to use integer division)

```
gr = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df.index.values))//4)
grp_order = (gr.sum()).sort_values('Value', ascending=False).index
```

Then print in the right order:

```
for idx in grp_order:
    print(idx)
    print(gr.get_group(idx))
    print('Cost: ', gr.get_group(idx).Value.sum())
```

Output:

```
1
                 Name     Role  Cost  Value
4      Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
5  Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
6          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
7         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
Cost:  165
2
                  Name     Role  Cost  Value
8          Baby Hitsuo   Driver   950     35
9   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
10          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
11         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30
Cost:  161
0
                 Name     Role  Cost  Value
0      Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39
1  Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46
2          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50
3        Greg Ritcher  Lookout   200     25
Cost:  160
```

Comment: Thank you, used this to get a better solution then I was initially looking for, great idea using the indexes I'll put it in my task box.

Answer (score 2):

Using `transform` create the additional key , then we sort the key by `sort_values`

```
df['key']=df['Value'].groupby(np.arange(len(df))//4).transform('sum')
df=df.sort_values('key',ascending=False)
df
Out[104]: 
                  Name     Role  Cost  Value  key
4       Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39  165
5   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46  165
6           Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50  165
7          Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30  165
8          Baby Hitsuo   Driver   950     35  161
9   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46  161
10          Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50  161
11         Appa Derren  Lookout   250     30  161
0       Johnny Tsunami   Driver  1000     39  160
1   Michael B. Jackson   Pistol  2500     46  160
2           Bobby Zuko   Pistol  3000     50  160
3         Greg Ritcher  Lookout   200     25  160
```

---

Notice I did not drop the key I created for sorting , you can do `df=df.drop('key',1)` to drop it .

Comment: why two slashes **(len(df))//4)** instead of one explain please, df['key']=df['Value'].groupby(np.arange(len(df))//4).transform('sum')

Comment: Is there another way to sort by the key while the dataframe is grouped by 4s. I'm asking because when i do this sort for whatever reason my Driver Pistol Pistol and Lookout are out of order per group like Pistol Driver Lookout Pistol. I want to maintain the original order per group of Driver Pistol Pistol Lookout after the sort.